# DOMXPath not finding display:none element

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to get the contents of a div by it's attribute value. It works for other divs but I can't seem to figure out why it won't work on this div.

```
<div id="js_taxonomy_data_a0d28860-428b-47c3-844f-81fae3306ced" data-test="taxonomy_data" style="display: none">...</div>
```

My query:

```
$element = $finder->query("//div[@data-test='taxonomy_data']");
```

Is it because the element style has display: none? I tried to search this question but couldn't find any comparable problems.

Comment: Are you sure that the `dataset` attribute was not added by javascript?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I disabled JavaScript in developer tools before I search for elements that I can query, so I think it is not added by JS.